# Why did God banish Adam and Eve for eating fruit?

Tags: adam-and-eve, fall-of-man, garden-of-eden

Yes, He told them not to but if you can humour me a little, why should this punishment be regarded as fitting the crime? It’s just fruit, right? Isn’t God testing our patience with such an injunction? Would you respect me if I told you not to touch my really delicious pot of lamb stew because you will be dead if you do, especially if the children are having a really tasty dinner?

Comment: Your question seems to be a continuation to your comments on my question. Clearfy your post much more in order not to get down votes. I up voted to you.

Comment: That’s okay, I can be ransomed by Him.

Comment: This question assumes the answer in its asking, that the fruit itself was the problem, which puts it into the realm of [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).  The answers you have received so far are each a challenge to the frame of the question.  (Valid challenges).

Comment: What assumption would that be?

Comment: Any child would ask why a loving

Comment: Take a screenshot folks. Stack is back to its old ways of deleting what they think is inconvenient to them.

Comment: God Himself said that eating the fruit will kill you. Adam and Eve ate the fruit and they were cursed. What about this is invalid since I asked why a loving and just God would be so spiteful that he would let you be cursed for eating an orange? Why would apple pie make you feel shame? Why would iced lemon tea powdered mixtures taste so foul without ice? Of course there are people who would prefer that the rest of us tthink it’s a literal fruit and so the reason for asking this question still stands. Once agains,

Comment: ....take a screenshot. You can’t trust these “literalist” moderators an inch. Reindeers are better than people......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed exactly what Adam and Eve missed - the tree of Life. There it was in the midst of the garden.

And there it was - the Word of Life - 'the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou dost not eat of it.'

It isn't food. You can't digest it. Partake of it and you will die.

But another (created) spirit drew near. (For they had not taken of the Tree of Life in the midst of the garden. They had not partaken of the Word of Life which said 'the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou dost not eat of it'.)

And Eve hearkened and ate. And Eve gave to Adam to eat.

And in that very day, they died.

This is about human nature. It is a matter of how humanity is to Live. Adam was made a living soul and he lived and breathed. But there was a Tree of Life in the midst which he needed. And he did not partake of it.

He chose to seek sustenance from another direction. From knowledge. Rather than partake of Life, he chose knowledge. Which assumes his own ability to see aright and to do aright what he sees.

Rather than to partake of Life itself.

He wishes to be independent of the Deity (in whom is Life) who made him.

Chooses to hearken to a created spirit, encouraged by a created woman.

And he dies.

And he is banished from the garden, for he has failed in his humanity to rise to the purpose of the Creator who made humanity for a purpose.

This is profoundly and fundamentally spiritual.

It's not about physical fruit.

Answer (score 3):

Most Christians would say that Adam and Eve's sin wasn't about eating fruit, but rebelling against God, their rightful and loving ruler. Sin can't be quantified in general, but especially not rebellion against God. What's the "fitting" punishment for rebels? Expulsion from the land of the ruler you rebelled against doesn't sound too unfitting. And they were still permitted to live in God's land actually, just not his special garden.

Comment: It still obivously was about fruit. Can I tell you not to eat an orange if I were the King of the Universe because if you do, you will be tried for treason against my scepter?

Comment: @Singleminded Why not?

Comment: That would make me a contradiction to the definition of Agape, that’s why not. Have you learned nothing of metaphors especially if you made faustian bargains for the sake of having Nikes instead of Payless shoes?

Comment: @SinglemindedCompass It is not about rebelling!!, Adam, Eve, the fruit and Satan are all One Entity...Adam. Eve is the Psych, I mean Adam is a Soul not Spirit. Eating from the fruit mean untrust in God. This is the case of the Psycho: when weak he feels: fear then untrust then unfaith, this in paradise [home of Spirits], when he is in his home (hell) [home of Souls] he become Arrogant then, finally, rebel against God. The Soul is dischizophrenic. The Soul has no Conscience. The Souls are the Adamic type of Humans. Hell=Home of Unreason.

Comment: @Salah That is not Christian teaching.

Comment: @curiousdannii I assure you these are my Ideas. Do you know a teaching to which my Ideas belong?

Comment: @salah you can always start your own church and see who shows up. 8^D

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thanks!!, I show you real understanding and real mystic, Sufi experience. Just examine it.

Answer (score 1):

Without the introduction of prohibition, human choice would have lain dormant and faith, having no opportunity to work, [would have been dead](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%202%3A14-26&version=ESV).  The fruit of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil was the item of prohibition.  But if you look at what the temptation was you will see that ingesting fruit is not what ruined mankind: Gen. 3:5

> "For God knows that when you eat of it your eyes will be opened, and
>   **you will be like God, knowing good and evil**."

The manifestation of the sin (the fruit of it, if you will) was eating from the prohibited tree.  The sin itself was in rejecting God as the one qualified to delineate between good and evil for him and in taking that mantle upon himself.  Adam died to the Word of God (the source of Life) as his governing authority in that moment because he claimed it for himself and internalized the desire to be his own 'god'.  [All of humanity](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015%3A22&version=ESV) has inherited that death.

The banishment from the garden was not penal but protective.  Gen. 3:22-24

> "Then the LORD God said, “Behold, the man has become like one of us in knowing good and evil. Now, **lest he reach out his hand and take also of the tree of life and eat, and live forever—**” therefore the LORD God sent him out from the garden of Eden to work the ground from which he was taken. He drove out the man, and at the east of the garden of Eden he placed the cherubim and a flaming sword that turned every way to **guard the way to the tree of life.**"

It is not good for man to live even a temporal life in the belief that he does not need God to discern good and evil for him.  God removed/cut off access to the Tree of Life so that man would not live forever in that state of spiritual death.  He sent His Son to be the new access point.

Comment: Can you explain to a five year old whether this fruit is a literal one or a metaphor for something else?

Comment: Both.  I believe it is a literal fruit that is emblematic of something more.  Much like the crossing of the Red Sea or the Passover.

Comment: What is your take on the symbolism?

Comment: Adam internalized a desire to reject God's authority and to determine good and evil for himself.  This is the fruit of the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil.  This is the 'original sin' every human since has been born with.  I believe there was an actual fruit but it was just fruit and it was the intention of Adam's heart that did him in.  The reason that I believe this is because the temptation wasn't so much to eat the fruit as it was to be like God.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Hi,  How do I highlight things in beige or yellow like you've done?

Comment: Use the quotes button in markdown.  When you go into edit, or when you begin an answer,, look at the top of the text box you are typing in.  You should see a little panel with various indications for bold, italics, quotes, links.  I think they are called "quote blocks" or something like that.